# Rosjava building test fails

Tags: ros, rosjava-core, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently upgraded to the gradle version of rosjava. When I build the test with #./gradlew test I got 16 errors. I checked the report and saw that the following errors occured:

```
MessageSerializationTest.testBool
MessageSerializationTest.testDuration
MessageSerializationTest.testFloat32
MessageSerializationTest.testFloat64
MessageSerializationTest.testInt16
MessageSerializationTest.testInt32
MessageSerializationTest.testInt64
MessageSerializationTest.testInt8
MessageSerializationTest.testNestedMessage
MessageSerializationTest.testNestedMessageArray
MessageSerializationTest.testString
MessageSerializationTest.testTime
MessageSerializationTest.testUInt16
MessageSerializationTest.testUInt32
MessageSerializationTest.testUInt64
MessageSerializationTest.testUint8
```

When checking all the errors, it says that the std_msgs/msg/ doesn't exist. (e.g)
"java.util.NoSuchElementException: Resource does not exist: /std_msgs/msg/Bool.msg"

ROS itself is installed and runns smoothly.

I am using ROS Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34134/rosjava-building-test-fails/) by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just pushed a fix for this.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0